# How to Write Out a Round in Sheet Music

Tags: notation, sheet-music, musical-forms, repeats

I'm trying to transcribe a song where the melody starts repeating in a round, so that after the first four eighth notes, the melody begins again. This can repeat as many as three times!

What is the best way to write this out in sheet music (preferably in one hand)?

Here is the melody, if it helps:
[image: a few bars of melody]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(music)

Answer (score 5):

There are two basic methods for straightforward rounds.

One is to write each "line" of the round on a separate staff, aligned vertically.

The other is to write the all the lines on one staff, and mark the places where each voice enters - often using an asterisk (*).

The title of the piece, or some other text, needs to make it clear that it *is* a round, and state the number of voices.

If the piece is more complicated (e.g. there are two different rounds going on at the same time, with different numbers of voices) it may be better just to write out the full score.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_(music) for examples.